# Error when Javascript 'or' || operator used in this case

Tags: javascript

So i have this situation basically

```
var a = someUndefinedVariable.name || "";
```

In this case why 'a' is not equal to an empty string???
This expression throws an error so I think execution just stops and Interpreter does not reaching to the part with the OR statement. Is it right?
However, without property name everything works fine.
Thanks a lot for attention.

Comment: Incomprensible question.

Comment: @MarcoSalerno, I comprehended it.

Comment: You guessed, it's different

Comment: I understood. It's not perfectly worded but the text correctly describes the entire problem.

Answer (score 6):

Because `someUndefinedVariable`, being `undefined`, doesn't have the property `name`, so it crashes. Replace it with:

```
var a = (someUndefinedVariable && someUndefinedVariable.name) || "";
```

Answer (score 4):

> This expression throws an error so I think execution just stops and Interpreter does not reaching to the part with the OR statement. Is it right?

Yes. Exceptions halt execution (unless you `catch` them).

> However, without property name everything works fine.

1. If a variable is not declared and you try to read from it, then you will get an exception: *Uncaught ReferenceError: foo is not defined*.
2. If a variable is declared, and has the `undefined` value, then you can access it freely. It is just `undefined`.
3. Trying to access a property of an `undefined` value throws an exception: 
   *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'bar' of undefined*

You are dealing with cases 2 and 3.

Answer (score 3):

You might check `someUndefinedVariable` first, to prevent an access to a property of a undefined variable

```
var a = someUndefinedVariable && someUndefinedVariable.name || "";
```

Comment: Nice tip! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you should use

```
var a = (someUndefinedVariable && someUndefinedVariable.name) || "";
```

since you are referring to a property of an undefined variable, it crashes, instead check if the variable exists before hand

Comment: Nice tip! Thanks!